# Is it safe to mix client and server code in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, security, next.js, serverless

Enjoying using NextJs for its ability to easily manage client and server code in the same framework.

Obviously I know that NextJS separates the code that it knows how to separate (e.g `getServerSideProps`), but is is safe to have client and server variables/helpers in the same file?

For example, let's say I have a file called `constants.ts` sitting somewhere in the codebase. If that file contains something like:

```
/* constants.ts */

export const REALLY_SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

export const NAME_OF_MY_SITE_FOR_USE_IN_FRONTEND_CODE = 'Mixing it Up'
```

Does NextJS do a reasonably good job of not leaking the `REALLY_SECRET_KEY` so long as I don't import it from a client-bound part of the code base? Like, how "secure" is its tree-shaking?

I'm aware that there are practical reasons for keeping stuff separate; both from an organisational front and to mitigate importing mistakes. But I'm curious as to whether this would be a serious security issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does a good job, but be careful with sensitive data! Always know what you do. [This tool may help](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/). Just copy your code and see what makes the way to the client bundle.